# Windows CMD Copy Command - PRN Files

Tags: windows, command-line

When I copy prn files to my printer using

```
copy filename.prn \\PC\Printer
```

And check the file in the printer queue it comes as Local Downlevel Document

Is there a way to specify a proper filename

Answer (score 1):

Just append a backslash and the desired filename:

```
copy filename.prn \\PC\Printer\filename.prn
```